# Download Manager for 19.04 and Clipboard Manager for 19.04

Tags: 19.04

Can someone help?

I want a download manager for Ubuntu 19.04, which one works?? XDM doesn't.

Also, which clipboard manager works for Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once." from [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions) in the section titled *Needs more focus*.

Answer (score 0):

Uget for download management and copyQ for clipboard management